# How to make sure that all codes in a do statement are executed by one thread using omp_lib in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, openmp

I am using parallel programming to shorten the time for reading data from files in Fortran. The input files are named as a combination of the string and integer with the change of the integer part(for example`file_`1 to `file_`10). Here is a full minimal example program. the function of the subroutine itoa is to change step number i to character (1 to '1',2 to '2' and so on); name_cre is to combine 'file_' and 'i' to create file name.

```
MODULE EQUATION
    contains
    SUBROUTINE itoa(i,res)
        INTEGER,INTENT(in) :: i
        CHARACTER(len=*),INTENT(out):: res
        CHARACTER(range(i)+2) :: tmp
        write(tmp,'(i5)') i
        res = trim(tmp)
    END SUBROUTINE itoa
    
    SUBROUTINE name_cre(f_n,s_n,res)
        CHARACTER(len=*),INTENT(in)::f_n,s_n
        CHARACTER(len=*),INTENT(out)::res
        res = adjustl(trim(f_n))//adjustl(trim(s_n))
    END SUBROUTINE name_cre
END MODULE EQUATION

    Program read
        use equation
        USE OMP_LIB
        implicit none
        integer:: i
        integer,dimension(1:10):: step=(/1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10/)
        Character(len = 100):: nu_part,s_name
        !$omp parallel do 
        DO i =1, 10
            CALL itoa(step(i),nu_part)
            CALL name_cre('file_',nu_part,s_name)
        WRITE(*,*) s_name
        END DO
        !$omp end parallel do
        READ(*,*)
    END Program read
```

I want all the statements in one do-loop is executed by one thread, so that the results should be something like

```
        file_1
        file_3
        file_2
        ....
```

or some different orders. But now, it seems that the first CALL is distributed to different thread and the second call is then distributed to another thread so that the results are something like

```
  file_1
  file_3
  file_3
  file_3
  ....
```

Thank you all, it seems that both `private(i,nu_part,s_name)` and `!$omp critical` can produce similar results I needed. Are there any differences between these two?

Comment: Please give a full, minimal example that shows the problem and that one can use to compile and run to help debug your problem.  My guess would be that you need to add something like `private(nu_part)` and `private(s_name)`, assuming that `char_part` is the `C_` part.

Comment: From the description you appear to have a loop that needs to be run in sequential order on a single thread. So why are you trying to parallelise it?

Comment: @MichaelKlemm Thanks, I've tried to edit the question, also I checked the private clause, but got some unreadable results.

Comment: @IanBush Thank you for your reply. This is only the first part of the do loop, in the following code, I will open the file and read data from it.  As there are lots of data in each file, I want to make sure each thread can handle part of the files to shorten the execution time.

Comment: What do you mean by "can handle part of the files"? Each read part of the data, or each process part of the data once one thread has read in? It really helps if, as requested you provide a *full* minimal example program which we can compile and run ...

Comment: Can you tell me what is the variable `step` here ?

Comment: @IanBush the question has been changed based on your suggestion.

Comment: @hakim I've tried to change the question to make it clear. the step is just a vector to store the integer part of the file name.

Comment: @Libin Your code doesn't compile. You should fix the name of the module. You wrote EUQUATION and not EQUATION. You should also declare the type of wck. What do you mean by `integer:: i,10` ? Did you forget `tot_sep` ?

Comment: @Libin I suppose that your `wck` is declared as an integer. Instead of `!$OMP DO PARALLEL`, write `!$OMP DO PARALLEL PRIVATE(i,nu_part,s_name)` and tell me if it works.

Comment: I suspect `wck` should be a character. Please fix the code and make sure that it compiles and runs as you claim, then, knowing it will behave as described, we can have a proper look

Comment: @hakim Thanks, It seems that `private` can make it works as I expected. I also tried  putting all the statements in Do-loop with `!$OMP CRITICAL`  and `!$OMP END CRITICAL`  and got similar results. Is there any difference with these two methods?

Comment: I wrote a blog post about parallelising the processing of a single file in OpenMP at https://cpufun.substack.com/p/processing-a-file-with-openmp that may be useful (though there I am worrying about treating each line in the file as a separate entity [re-implementing `grep`])